# filter more than one space in EditText (Android)

Tags: java, android, spacing

I need to restrict the users from entering more than one space between words. Is there any way to limit the user with only one space per word???

```
if (validateStatus
                && RegistraionRequestType.RegisterationCompleteReq.descdet.trim()
                .length() < 50) {
            Log.e("Validate----------------------  ",RegistraionRequestType.RegisterationCompleteReq.descdet+ "    --ValidateXCalled");
            warning = getResources().getString(R.string.description_msg);
            registeration_frm_et_id_description.requestFocus();
            validateStatus = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            editText.setText(s.toString().trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    String temp = s.toString();
                    temp.replace("  ", " ");
                    editText.setText(temp);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call EditText.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher)

then implement your own TextWatcher interface.

The key is

```
    afterTextChanged(Editable s)
```

You can check the existing text inside the EditText from the first parameter. If the last character are 2 consecutive spaces, you can programmatically set the text to its substring(0, length-1).

Answer (score 0):

I know its too old question to answer, still wanted to share some useful code as a solution :

```
private InputFilter spaceFilter() {
    return new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                   Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (Character.isWhitespace(source.charAt(i))) {
                    if (dstart == 0 || (dstart > 1 && dest.charAt(dstart - 1) == ' ')) return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @PratikMohanraoGondil : It's working for me, please show me your code snippet so that I can look into it

Comment: by `dstart == 0 || (dstart > 1` did you mean `i`? instead of `dstart`?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove the multiple spaces, use the code below:

```
string.replaceAll("\\s", " ");
```

Hope it helps!!